# Card items inside of a accordion class not being horizontal positioned BOOTSTRAP 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to align these accordion items horizontally. For whatever reason though they refuse I am using bootstrap 4 and I know that the method I'm using works in bootstrap 3 if anyone can provide a fix for this it would be greatly appreciated.

jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bhb6q929/

HTML

```
<div class="container">


<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2"> </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                            <h5 class="mb-0 text-center">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Type
        </a>
      </h5> </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                                <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default card-block" aria-label="Left Align"> <img src="http://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/g/gd/makefg.php?i=../assets/preview/2012/png/iconmonstr-laptop-4.png&r=0&g=0&b=0"> </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default card-block" aria-label="Left Align"> <img src="http://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/g/gd/makefg.php?i=../assets/preview/2012/png/iconmonstr-tablet-1.png&r=0&g=0&b=0"> </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default card-block" aria-label="Left Align"> <img src="http://iconmonstr.com/wp-content/g/gd/makefg.php?i=../assets/preview/2012/png/iconmonstr-smartphone-3.png&r=0&g=0&b=0"> </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                            <h5 class="mb-0 text-center">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Model
        </a>
      </h5> </div>
                        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                            <div class="card-block"> Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                            <h5 class="mb-0 text-center">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h5> </div>
                        <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                            <div class="card-block"> Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2"> </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    padding: 0px;
}
body {
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 1.52947;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: -0.021em;
    font-family: "SF Pro Text","SF Pro Icons","Helvetica Neue","Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    color: #333;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tiny CSS code will do the job.

```
.card{float:left;}
```

And I also suggest removing the accordion first one show class

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" ....>
```

to

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" ...>
```

Comment: So I removed the class and all my row and colums and refreshed before i added you css and it fixed it then i added your css and it broke it XD don't know why but if you didnt tell me to remove the class it wouldn't have worked so heres a check mark :D

Comment: No reason for the extra CSS. Bootstrap 4 has a `.float-left` class for this.

Comment: Hehe, I am a noobie. This Zim guy knows pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 4, use a nested grid like this.

```
 <div id="accordion" class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col">
              <div class="card">..</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
              <div class="card">..</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
              <div class="card">..</div>
          </div>
 </div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/BVmPyKItT4

`float:left` won't work very well when the accordions are opened.

Comment: Zim, maybe it's just me but the codeply link is not loading, remains on the three points loading screen endlessly, tried on several browsers.

Comment: Sadly no but thanks though, very weird maybe it's just me, I'll have to try it tomorrow at the office. Console throws the following: https://imgur.com/a/VSFKx